# Strictly increasing infinite sequence can not exist in the set $S_k:=\{\frac{1}{n_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n_k}\mid n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, contest-math

Consider the following problem:

For each positive integer $k$, let $S_k$ be the set of real numbers that can be expressed in the form
$$\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n_k}$$
where $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$ are positive integers.
Prove that $S_k$ doesn't contain a strictly increasing infinite sequence.

---

The following is my attempt, but I am not sure if it is correct because this solution seems to be leaning towards real analysis, which I really did not expect while starting out on the problem(I expected it to be number theoretic in nature).

Let us fix a $k$ first. Let $(s_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a increasing sequence in $S_k$.
With each $s_i$ in the sequence, we can associate a tuple $N_i:=(\frac{1}{n_{1,i}},\frac{1}{n_{2,i}},\cdots, \frac{1}{n_{k,i}})$ such that
$$\frac{1}{n_{1,i}}+\frac{1}{n_{2,i}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n_{k,i}}=s_i$$
But $(N_i)_{i\ge 1}$ is a sequence in $I^k$ where $I=[0,1]$. Since $I^k$ is compact, $(N_i)$ must have a convergent sub-sequence. By re-indexing the sequence, we assume that $(N_i)$ is a converging sequence. But then $(\frac{1}{n_{i,j}})_{j\ge 1}$ must be converging for $1\le i\le k$. But any sequence in $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ converges to either $0$ or $\frac{1}{n}$(by using a eventually constant sequence). The $(N_i)_{i\ge 1}$ must converge to some $k$-tuple $A:=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k)$, where $a_i=0$ or $\frac{1}{m_i}$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ for $1\le i\le k$. If $a_i=\frac{1}{m_i}$ for some $i$, then we must have $n_{i,j}=m_i$ for large enough $j$. Thus it is possible to pick a large enough $M$ such that the slots where $(n_{i,j})_{j\ge 1}$ is converging to some $\frac{1}{m_i}$, are all constant(hence equal to $\frac{1}{m_i}$) for $j\ge M$. Now consider $d_{\infty}(A,N_M)$ where $d_{\infty}$ denotes the $L^{\infty}$ metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$. Let $N_0$ be the largest of the $n_{i,M}$. Since $N_i\to A$, we must have $d_{\infty}(N_i,A)<\frac{1}{2N_0}$ for $i\ge M_1$. Let $M_2=\max(M_1,M)$. Then $s_{M_2}<s_M$, a contradiction because $s_i$ is a increasing sequence.

Comment: Fix $k$. Take a $\epsilon >0$. Then there are only finite number of elements of $S_k$ such that $x \in S_k$ and $x > \epsilon$. This is enough to proof the claim.

Comment: @Salcio I don't think your claim is true, because for $S_2$, if you take $\epsilon =1$, then $1+\frac{1}{n}>1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sorry, you have to modify this idea slightly ...  Fix $k$. Take $x \in S_k$, say $x=\sum \frac{1}{n_l}$ If $y \in S_k$ is such that $y > x$ and $y=\sum \frac{1}{m_l}$ then if we show that for some $l$ we must have $m_l < n_l$ we are done (i.e. we iterate).

Comment: @Salcio That's not entirely enough on its own. Because while yes, at least one denominator has to decrease, at the same time other denominators can increase (e.g. you can go from $\frac12+\frac13$ to $\frac11+\frac1{653\,938\,532}$, and that's a _simple_ example). You have to show that the decreases are "strong" enough compared to the increases that you can still only go through it a finite number of times.

Comment: I think you can simplify the end of the proof: once you know that each sequence of unit fractions either tends to 0 or is eventually constant, then you can compare the limit to the supremum (which should be the same for increasing sequences but is clearly not the same here).

Comment: Overall, it's probably cleaner to use your ideas to prove a more general statement: if $S$ and $T$ are sets of real numbers with no strictly increasing infinite subsequences, then $S+T$ has that same property. The desired statement follows from this and induction on $k$.

Comment: @GregMartin Do we need $S,T$ to be bounded. If it is so, then my proof would carry over almost without any change. But I don't see how to do it for any S,T.

Comment: They're automatically bounded above; I don't know if bounded below is necessary or not, but sure assume it if you like :) Come to think of it, the negatives of these sets are the ones that are well-ordered by $<$, so there might already be a theorem to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do with by induction.

The base case $k = 1$ is trivial.

The induction hypothesis is that there does not exist a strictly increasing infinite sequence in $S_k$.

Now assume that there exists a strictly increasing sequence $(x_m)$ in $S_{k+1}$. Each $x_m$ has the form $x_m = s_m + \dfrac{1}{n_m}$ with $s_m \in S_k$ and $n_m \in \mathbb N$. The sequence $\left(\dfrac{1}{n_m}\right)$ is a sequence in $(0,1]$, thus we may assume w.l.o.g. that $\dfrac{1}{n_m} \to t \in [0,1]$. If $\dfrac{1}{n_m}$ attains only finitely many values, then $t$ must be one of these values and we may w.l.o.g. assume that $\left(\dfrac{1}{n_m}\right)$ is constant. If $\dfrac{1}{n_m}$ attains infinitely many values, then we get $t = 0$ and we may assume w.l.o.g. that $\left(\dfrac{1}{n_m}\right)$ is strictly decreasing. In both cases $\left(\dfrac{1}{n_m}\right)$  is non-increasing. This implies that $(s_m)$ must be strictly increasing in order that $(x_m)$ is strictly increasing. This contradicts the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very nice and short solution.